# About the cases when $N=N(\epsilon)$ is bounded or unbounded

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

The limit of the sequence $(x_n)$ is $x$ if for each $\epsilon >0$ there exists a positive integer $N=N(\epsilon)$ such that $|x_n−x|<\epsilon$ for all $n≥N.$

I am asking about the cases when $N=N(\epsilon)$ is bounded or unbounded, i.e., when $\epsilon$ tending to zero. I can find examples such that $N=N(\epsilon)$ is bounded or unbounded. But I am interested on the general case.

Comment: It is very unclear what you want here. I'm voting to close until you can ask a clear question.

Comment: @Rhys: I am asking about the nature of the number $N$ when $ε→0$.

Comment: That is so strongly dependent on the nature of the sequence that no general statements can be made. You've already said that you can find examples where is is bounded and unbounded. What, specifically, do you want to know?

Comment: @Rhys: Ok. You said that no general statements can be made. This is the answer I am looking for.

Comment: General statements can be made, I'm working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you cannot determine the behaviour in $\epsilon$ of the sharpest $N(\epsilon)$. By sharp I mean that $N(\epsilon)$ is such that $|x-x_n|<\epsilon$ if $n\geq N(\epsilon)$ and $|x-x_n|\geq\epsilon$ if $n<N(\epsilon)$.

Put it differently, $N:(0,+\infty)\to\mathbb{N}$ defined as $N(\epsilon)=\inf\{N\in\mathbb{N}:|x-x_n|\leq\epsilon\text{ whenever }n\geq N\}$ is monotone but not necessarily unbounded. However, asking this sharp condition on $N(\epsilon)$ is a surplus with respect to the definition of limit: "it exists an $N(\epsilon)$" means that you have the freedom of the choice of it, since you are interested in an asymptotic behaviour of the sequence. Therefore, in $N(\epsilon)$ is the sharpest value for a given $\epsilon>0$, also $N(\epsilon)+1000$ is acceptable in the definition of the limit. This means that, recursively, you can always made your choice of $N$ growing faster and faster, and made it unbounded. The reverse is clearly non possible.

Answer (score 2):

In general, if we have a sequence $(x_{n})$ converging to some $x$ and we take $N(\varepsilon)$ to be the smallest integer such that for all $n\geq N(\varepsilon)$ we have $|x_{n}-x|<\varepsilon$, then $X=\{N(\varepsilon):\varepsilon>0\}$ is bounded if and only if there exists an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x_{n}=x$ for all $n\geq N$.

First suppose that $X$ is a bounded set. Then $X$ is finite, so we can find a $\varepsilon'$ such that $N(\varepsilon')=\max X$. In particular, for all $0<\varepsilon<\varepsilon'$ we have $N(\varepsilon)=\max X$, as 
$$\max X\geq N(\varepsilon)\geq N(\varepsilon')=\max X.$$
Hence for all $n\geq\max X$ we have
$$|x_{n}-x|\leq\lim_{\varepsilon\downarrow0}\varepsilon=0,$$
so $x_{n}=x$.

Now suppose that there exists and $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq N$ we have that $x_{n}=x$. Then for all $\varepsilon>)$ we have that $N(\varepsilon)\leq N$, so $X$ is bounded.